# How do I toggle verbose mode for all commands inside tox.ini in a simpler way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tox

Let us say I have a lot of commands inside my tox.ini

```
commands =
        poetry install -v
        poetry run pytest --typeguard-packages=news --xdoctest --cov -vv
        poetry run flake8 --verbose
        poetry run black src tests --verbose
        poetry run isort . --verbose
        poetry run bandit src --recursive --verbose
        poetry run mypy src --verbose
        poetry run darglint src --verbosity=2
        poetry run darglint tests --verbosity=2
```

Instead of repeating verbose everywhere, is there a way I can make all of them run with/without verbose in a simpler way?

For example, if I ran

```
poetry run tox
```

it runs everything without verbose, if I remove the --verbose flag from everywhere
but how do I make tox run all commands with verbose without hardcoding the verbose flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no simpler way, as you can see that the commands take different arguments to run in verbose mode.

If all commands would take the same arguments, e.g. `--verbose`, you could do something like...

```
commands =
        poetry install {posargs}
        poetry run pytest --typeguard-packages=news --xdoctest --cov {posargs}
        poetry run flake8 {posargs}
        poetry run black src tests {posargs}
        ...
```

and then run

```
tox -e lint -- --verbose
```

That said... "there is no way" is a lie.

You could create a bash script and run that as a tox command instead of your current list.

P.S.: I am one of the tox maintainers, but not a bash guy :-) So good luck with that.

P.P.S.: Out of scope of this question, but you could have a look at https://pre-commit.com/ - this is the way most Python projects I know run linters nowadays.

P.P.P.S.: You could copy/paste your env, one time with and one time without the verbose mode.

Comment: i have pre-commit setup, how does the P.P.P.S mode work :)

Comment: haha.. https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/zbjpwQH8f8/ - yeah, a lot of duplication

And if you have a pre-commit setup you could run your linters like...

tox -e lint

tox config see
https://github.com/jugmac00/flask-reuploaded/blob/d943061e83fbdf1c7d3ce56f59d6aa131f3649cd/tox.ini#L24-L26